# Не могу подключиться к локальному серверу MySQL из C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

```
string connetionString;
SqlConnection cnn;
connetionString = @"Data Source=127.0.0.1:3306;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=root;Password=0000";
cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
    cnn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Хочу подключиться к локальному серверу MySQL через приложение C#, но получаю ошибку с первого скрина: `named pipes provider error 40`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользователь "root", пароль "0000", но уже в MySQL Workbranch в тестовом соединении проходят успешно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я пытался дать этими командами на сервере доступ:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL и MS SQL (Microsoft SQL Server) - это разные SQL, от разных производителей. Вы пытаетесь использовать классы от MS SQL (System.Data.SqlClient) для работы с MySQL. Не получится. У них совершенно разные протоколы.

Для подключения к MySQL вам нужно поставить пакет [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) и использовать классы из него.